# ¿como puedo agregar datos a un listview personalizado de un array?

Tags: java

este es el array que quiero llenar en el listview

["Tomate","5000","2000"]["Cebolla","100","200"]

el problema es que al momento de agregar los datos al list view no me aparecen en orden como yo quisiera, aparece el listview asi:

Tomate     100      200

5000       100      200

un ejemplo que vi utilizaba los datos de esta forma y asi funcionaba pero en mi caso no se como:

declaraba estos datos en el mainactivity:

Strin[][] datos ={{"tomate","1000","200"}{"cebolla","300","200"}}

pasaba al adaptador de la siguiente manera:

lvProductos.setAdapter(new Adaptador(getApplicationContext(), datos[][]));

y en el adaptador declaraba de la siguiente manera:

public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

```
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
Context contexto;
datos[][] datos;
TextView tvIzquierda, tvCentro, tvDerecha;

public Adaptador(Context contexto, datos[][]) {
    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.ja = ja;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(contexto.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null);


    tvIzquierda = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tvCentro = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tvDerecha = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tv3);

    tvIzquierda.setText(datos[i][0]);
    tvCentro.setText(datos[i][1]);
    tvDerecha.setText(datos[i][2]);


    return vista;
}
```

en el ejemplo se utilizaba en la vista de el getview con un contador para agregar los elementos al listview y en mi caso no se como utilizar ese contador y no se si sea necesario, creo que el problema radica en que los datos no esta pasando a la siguiente fila como deberia ser.

el codigo es el siguiente:

//CODIGO ADAPTADOR

public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

```
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
Context contexto;
ArrayList<String> ja;
TextView tvIzquierda, tvCentro, tvDerecha;

public Adaptador(Context contexto, ArrayList<String> ja) {
    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.ja = ja;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(contexto.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null);


    tvIzquierda = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tvCentro = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tvDerecha = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tv3);

    for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j+=3) {
            tvIzquierda.setText(ja.get(i));
            tvCentro.setText(ja.get(j+1));
            tvDerecha.setText(ja.get(j+2));
    }

    return vista;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ja.size()/3;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

//CODIGO MAINACTIVITY

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView tvIzquierda;
EditText etBuscar;
ListView lvProductos;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String consulta = "http://bdplaza.nv.ax/selectTodo.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etBuscar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBuscarProducto);
    lvProductos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvBusqueda);

    tvIzquierda = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    lvProductos.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    EnviarRecibirDatos(consulta);

}


public void EnviarRecibirDatos(String URL) {

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            response = response.replace("][", ",");

            if (response.length() >= 0) {
                try {
                    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(response);
                    Log.i("sizejson", "" + ja.length());
                    final ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i <= ja.length(); i += 1) {

                        try {
                            lista.add(ja.getString(i));

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    lvProductos.setAdapter(new Adaptador(getApplicationContext(), lista));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese for que tienes en getView no tiene ningún sentido. Si asumes que en tu lista de cadenas, cada tres cadenas es un elemento, no puedes hacer esto:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j+=3) {
    tvIzquierda.setText(ja.get(i));
    tvCentro.setText(ja.get(j+1));
    tvDerecha.setText(ja.get(j+2));
}
```

La i es la posición del item, si seleccionas el primero, te llega un 0, selecionarías 4 veces que das vuelta al bucle la primera cadena de tu array. Si seleccionas el segundo te llega un 1, y tomas la segunda cadena de tu array, pero oh, esa no es, debería ser la cuarta. Porque la segunda y la tercera forman parte del primer elemento (cada tres cadenas un elemento). Y también 4 veces porque está en un bucle.... No tiene sentido.

Recomendación. No uses un `ArrayList<String>`, sino un `ArrayList<TuClase>`. Crea un objeto de una clase tuya que contenga las tres cadenas:

```
class TuClase {
    public String izquierda;
    public String centro;
    public String derecha;
}
```

Pásale y guarda en el adaptador el `ArrayList<TuClase>` con tus objetos. Y en `getView` sería tan sencillo como ir al `ArayList`, a la posición `i`, y obtener los valores `izquierda`, `centro` y `derecha` de ese objeto:

```
public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

    ...
    ArrayList<MiClase> ja;

    ...
    public Adaptador(Context contexto, ArrayList<MiClase> ja) {
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.ja = ja;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ...
        tvIzquierda.setText(ja.get(i).izquierda);
        tvCentro.setText(ja.get(i).centro);
        tvDerecha.setText(ja.get(i).derecha);

        return vista;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me queda claro porque no funcionaba y como funciona la clase adaptador, pero lo que no me queda claro es como puedo llenar el ArrayList<MiClase> con mis datos ya que actualmente estoy pasando un ArrayList<String> y ahi estoy guardando los datos que obtengo del JSON tal y como se puede ver acontinuacion:

Comment: JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(response);
                        Log.i("sizejson", "" + ja.length());
                        final ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i <= ja.length(); i += 1) {

                            try {
                                lista.add(ja.getString(i));

                            } 
                        }
                        
                        lvProductos.setAdapter(new Adaptador(getApplicationContext(), ));

Comment: entonces me gustaria saber como puedo llenar el ArrayList<MiClase> con mis datos si no puedo utilizar el ja.getString(i) en el for, muchas gracias.

Comment: y perdone mi ignorancia, es que hasta ahora estoy aprendiendo

Comment: Si siempre vienen de 3 en 3,puedes hacer que en cada vuelta del bucle tomes cada 3 cadenas, crees un objeto y lo añadas a la lista. Piénsalo un poco que es muy sencillo.